# Change the numtxqueues and numrxqueues of an interface

Tags: networking

I am running a network topology using Mininet. I want to change the numtxqueues and numrxqueues of my interface (h1-eth0).

I execute the following command:`ip link set h1-eth0 numtxqueues 8 numrxqueues 8`, although it seems to run, I realize (`ls /sys/class/net/h1-eth0/queues`) that the number of the queues is still 1 (RTX-0, MTX-0).

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.5

Where is my mistake?